# How can I combine blocks of the same type in rectangular prisms in an efficient mannor?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making a block-based city building game and I'm trying to figure out an efficient way of merging multiple blocks of the same type into boxes for optimization purposes. So let's say there's a wall of a building and it's 16x30x16 blocks of brick. Rather than draw the 7,680 blocks, I can draw them as one giant flat rectangular prism with a repeating texture, which would be eons more efficient.

I started on this by creating strips, which I intended to further combine into panes, but it seems that this method is already too slow, as it has to loop through every block in a plot(chunk), check if it can be merged into the current strip, and then merge it if yes.

Thanks in advance

```
local function Draw(plot)
    local blocks = plot.blocks
    local slabs = NewAutotable(3)
    local slabList = {}
    for y = 1, 32 do
        for x = 1, 16 do
            local currentSlab = NewSlab(x, y, 1, 1, 1, 1, blocks[x][y][1])
            slabs[x][y][1] = currentSlab
            slabList[#slabList + 1] = currentSlab
            for z = 2, 16 do
                if currentSlab[7] == blocks[x][y][z] then
                    GrowSlab(currentSlab, 0, 0, 1)
                else
                    currentSlab = NewSlab(x, y, z, 1, 1, 1, blocks[x][y][z + 1])
                    slabs[x][y][z] = currentSlab
                    slabList[#slabList + 1] = currentSlab
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to render all of the blocks? Could you make it a single block that is 16x30x16 and just put a single texture on each face with a Decal?

Comment: Because I don't know what it's dealing with. I never know what somebody might build, so I'd have to have it be able to handle anything.